# Get value from MySQL by received ID in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Trying to get from same (wp_postmeta) table with different queries some information next to the printed result.
In example - I'm trying to get:

1. ID
2. "_hover" meta key of left ID
3. "_sku" meta_value which belongs to same ID (1.)

What I'm doing wrong?

```
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_hover'";
$sql = "SELECT meta_value = '_sku' FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = post_id";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["post_id"]. " - meta value: " . $row["meta_value"]. " - sku: ".$row["meta_value ='_sku'"]."<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Your second query overwrites the first since you're storing it in the same variable. And the `WHERE` statement in the second makes zero sense. When wouldn't a value in a column be equal to itself? Either way, why don't you use Wordpress own [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function to get metadata instead of rolling your own?

Comment: I need that to export certain info which can't be exported with any export plugin. Reason is simple - old "fashion" code writes directly in database by post ID.